# How do I determine if a value is between range of values specified in two columns and return another value from the row where condition is true?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a value that I enter in cell B5.  I need a value returned from column C and the corresponding row where the value is between minimum values in A10:A12 and maximum values in B10:B12.  In the example below the value in C11 (0.025) is returned:

B5 = 11

```
 A    B     C
 0   10   0.0023
10   20   0.025
20   30   0.11
```

Comment: Do you mean for `B12` to be 10?  It looks like it should be 30, or at least something > 20.

Answer (score 1):

If you will always have `A10` < `A11` < `A12`, …, and `B10` = `A11`, `B11` = `A12`, …, and `B5` ≥ `A10` and `B5` ≤ `B12`, then `VLOOKUP` gives a quick answer:

```
=VLOOKUP(B5, $A$10:$C$12, 3)
```

Note that this actually ignores `B10`:`B12`, so any `B5` value ≥ 20 will give you 0.11 (the specified result for 10-20). 
If you want `B12` honored as an upper limit, add a row 13 with `A13` = `=B12`, `B13` is anything (or nothing), and `C13` = `#N/A`, and change the `12` in the `VLOOKUP` formula to `13`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ranges don't have gaps (as looks to be the case) then it's sufficient to use just the lower bounds in col A, i.e.

`=LOOKUP(B5,A10:A12,C10:C12)`

Comment: Beat you by 18 seconds!  :-)

Comment: Nah! it was only 17...............